# How to command cmd using batch file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd.exe

I would like to make a batch file that:

1.open cmd.exe

2.command cmd to open a directory.

3.make a new directory by using command mkdir inside the cmd.

How can I do this?

Comment: I've typed "batch file" into Google, here's [second result](http://www.wikihow.com/Write-a-Batch-File).

Answer (score 1):

a batch file is processessed within a cmd.

So you juste have to enter in your batch

> cd "absolute path of your directory"
>
> mkdir "folder name"

But powershell is much more powerful than batch which is kinda obsolete.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Notepad or any text editor
2. type the commands as is in the file.(in the manner you type on cmd)
   Here,

   `cd "absolute/path/of/the/directory"
    mkdir "folder_name"`
3. Save it as a '.bat' file.
4. Execute it. Job done.